# Is there a way to just click image hyperlinks in an external html email signature in outlook 2013 rather than having to ctrl+click?

Tags: html, outlook, mouseevent, html-email, outlook-2013

the signature is working fine elsewhere. I'd like to be able to just click on the image hyperlinks rather than Ctrl + click to follow the path in Outlook 2013. Is there something I'm missing or is this a preference in outlook 2013? Thanks for your help

Comment: It's a preference for emails you're composing.  Should just work for emails you've received, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

go to Tools > Options

cLick on editor options

[image]

Click on Advanced and uncheck "use CTRL+click to follow hyperlink"

[image]